# Bluej math tester class error

Tags: java, interface, bluej

again I have a computer science question.  I am doing a lab for AP computer science in which we are given 2 skeleton codes and a tester class and a interface class.  Our job is to make the tester run with no errors.  The code I got was a triangle math code (side length, perimeter, area, that sort of thing).  I made it so it would all run, but one of the tests keeps failing. I dont know why, please help me.
Here is the triangle main code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Triangle implements TestableTriangle
{
    private int sideA, sideB, sideC;
    private double perimeter;
    private double theArea;

    public Triangle()
    {
       setSides(0,0,0);
       perimeter=0;
       theArea=0;
    }

    public Triangle(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        sideA=a;
        sideB=b;
        sideC=c;
    }

    public void setSides(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        sideA=a;
        sideB=b;
        sideC=c;
    }

    public void calcPerimeter( )
    {
        perimeter=(sideA+sideB+sideC);


    }

    public void calcArea( )
    {
        double s;
        s=(perimeter/2);
        theArea=(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));


    }

    public void print( )
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println(sideA+" "+sideB+" "+sideC+"\n");
    }

    public int getSideA()
    {
        return sideA;
    }

    public int getSideB()
    {
        return sideB;     
    }

    public int getSideC()
    {
        return sideC;
    }
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return perimeter;
    }
    public double getTheArea()
    {
        return theArea;
    }

}
```

Here is the lab code. This class is used to test Triangle

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math.*;
public class Lab03a  //this class is used to test Triangle
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ask for user input
        System.out.print("Enter side A ::  ");
        int a = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter side B ::  ");
        int b = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter side C ::  ");
        int c = keyboard.nextInt();


        Triangle test = new Triangle(a, b, c);
        test.calcPerimeter();
        test.calcArea();
        test.print();


        //ask for user input
        System.out.print("Enter side A ::  ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter side B ::  ");
        b = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter side C ::  ");
        c = keyboard.nextInt();


        test.setSides(a,b,c);
        test.calcPerimeter();
        test.calcArea();
        test.print();


        //add one more input section
        System.out.print("Enter side A ::  ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter side B ::  ");
        b = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter side C ::  ");
        c = keyboard.nextInt();


        test.setSides(a,b,c);
        test.calcPerimeter();
        test.calcArea();
        test.print();
    }
}
```

Here is the interface code:

```
public interface TestableTriangle
{
    public void setSides(int a, int b, int c);

    public void calcPerimeter( );

    public void calcArea( );

    public void print( );

    public int getSideA();

    public int getSideB();

    public int getSideC();

    public double getPerimeter();

    public double getTheArea();
}
```

Here is the tester code (and below it is the error message it shows):
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;

```
public class TriangleTest
{
    private Triangle triangle1;

    /**
     * Default constructor for test class TriangleTest
     */
    public TriangleTest()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the test fixture.
     *
     * Called before every test case method.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {

        triangle1 = new Triangle(37, 38, 39);
    }

    /**
     * Tears down the test fixture.
     *
     * Called after every test case method.
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructorAndSides()
    {
        //Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(35, 36, 37);
        assertEquals(37, triangle1.getSideA());
        assertEquals(38, triangle1.getSideB());
        assertEquals(39, triangle1.getSideC());
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructorAndPerimeter()
    {
        //Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(36, 37, 38);
        assertEquals(0.0, triangle1.getPerimeter(), 0.1);
        triangle1.calcPerimeter();
        assertEquals(114.0, triangle1.getPerimeter(), 0.1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetSidesAndSides()
    {
        //Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(37, 38, 39);
        triangle1.setSides(10, 15, 16);
        assertEquals(10, triangle1.getSideA());
        assertEquals(15, triangle1.getSideB());
        assertEquals(16, triangle1.getSideC());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetSidesAndPerimeter()
    {
        Triangle triangle2 = new Triangle();
        triangle2.calcPerimeter();
        assertEquals(0.0, triangle2.getPerimeter(), 0.1);
        triangle2.setSides(38, 39, 40);
        assertEquals(0.0, triangle2.getPerimeter(), 0.1);
        triangle2.calcPerimeter();
        assertEquals(117.0, triangle2.getPerimeter(), 0.1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetSidesAndTheArea()
    {
        Triangle triangle2 = new Triangle();
        assertEquals(0.0, triangle2.getTheArea(), 0.1);
        triangle2.setSides(12, 13, 14);
        triangle2.calcArea();
        assertEquals(-0.0, triangle1.getTheArea(), 0.1);
        triangle2.calcPerimeter();
        triangle2.calcArea();
        assertEquals(72.30794, triangle2.getTheArea(), 0.00001);
    }


}
```

And the error message said something was wrong with this line:

`assertEquals(72.30794, triangle2.getTheArea(), 0.00001);`

for some reason it causes it to fail.  I do not know why, everything else works perfectly.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
-Keelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to take the square root of the expression you got for the area. And it seems that you are not using the right variable names:

```
public void calcArea( )
{
    // ensure perimeter is up-to-date!
    calcPerimeter();
    double s = (perimeter / 2.0);
    theArea = Math.sqrt(s * (s - sideA) * (s - sideB) * (s - sideC));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
theArea=(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
```

should be

```
theArea=Math.sqrt((s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have ill-code while calculating area of the triangle.
It should be as follows:

```
public void calcArea( )
{
    double s;
    s=(perimeter/2);
    theArea=Math.sqrt((s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)));


}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, thanks all of you.  I feel really stupid right now, I'm looking at the notes the teacher put online, and there it is, in bold "ALL SPECIAL MATH OPERATIONS MUST HAVE 'Math.' IN FRONT OF THEM"...  DERP!

Comment: @KeelenBerkenkotter : I am glad you got to the issue of your program. This was a small mistake. Rest of the program looks good and well organized.